# TFS copy build output to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I have been working with a TFS project that supports copying build output to source control. If I open the build definition, this is under "Build Defaults". There is an option to copy build output to a source control folder.

I have just installed TFS Server 2013 (with update 2) and I want to use this feature with a new Team Project. However, if I create new build in VS 2012 or VS 2013 on the new server, I am not given the option to copy build output to source control. What gives?

I am not looking for a workaround, I want to know what to change so that my server acts like the first one I described. Thanks!

Screenshots of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wadDR.jpg

Comment: This begs the question, "why?" Build artifacts really shouldn't be source controlled.

Comment: Are you choosing the right template?

Comment: I'm intrigued, can you add a screen shot of the original please.

Comment: @DanielMann I know that. I'm trying to mimic the original project.

Comment: @JustTFS http://imgur.com/a/mhDNQ I'm not sure how to select one of my templates. VS has chosen a strange location for where it is pulling its TvfcTemplate.12.xaml and I do not know how to specify a directory where I have my own templates.

Comment: Edit your question and add the images, so it's easier to see. Ok it's a vs11 option. https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/03/13/Dropping-build-output-to-source-control-in-TFS11.aspx

Comment: The original project is using visualstudio.com, and I'm using TFS 2013 (aka VS12). These are obviously both newer than VS11.

Comment: If you know you shouldn't, and you don't have a reason to do it, then why are you doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a feature that was temporarily present in TFS, but I believe has since been removed.  If I recall it was put in there specifically to support the cloud-hosted elastic build servers which didn't have access to network shares to drop the builds in.

Most people recommend against putting your build outputs into TFS.  The best approach is to publish them to a NuGet feed.

In any case if you want to put your build outputs into TFS (or a NuGet feed) you'll have to modify the build workflow to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you. The existing build controller I am trying to replicate must have that version.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new build definition > process.

Under template select new and you should be able to choose project and folder. Find your original template and link it. Your option should appear.

Comment: It seems like it would, but it just doesn't. Additionally Solution Explorer absolutely refuses to display or let me open .sln files which I know are checked-in. This is a disaster (but it's not your fault).

Comment: Well I would edit your question. How can I replicate vsonline's check in to source control after build function? This was never a part of TFS on premise, but allegedly there was a toolbox item? To replicate the process. You'd just have to roll it yourself

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that it was a vsonline-only feature.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2013 this has changed to be "store drops in TFS". When you select this option the drop I'd stored in a new inversioned store that you can access.

While you can easily get the files out as indecision or zips the built in tools like release management do not support it yet. I would recommend that you use this option but publish your assets to a nugget repository.

If your TFS is available online (VSO or https) then you can use MyGet to dynamically load the nugget packages that you are publish and make them available on a feed.

http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/use-tfs-online-git-with-myget-build-services